# Overwatch not playing in 5.1 surround sound, just in stereo

Tags: overwatch, audio-hardware

Has anyone gotten 5.1 or 7.1 to work?

I don't mean simulated surround in Dolby Atmos headphhones.

I don't mean "Speaker Fill" or emulated surround sound either. I mean true 5.1 positional surround sound with 5 speakers and a sub.

Oddly, in another Blizzard game, Heroes of the Storm, it works.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. It turned out I had my hardware set up wrong and didn't even realize it. It works out of the box and auto-detects from windows system settings.